# Auto Cron is Not Working When I want to add Data into DataBase

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3, cron

> Here data was successfully addded into database when i run **php bin\magento cron:run** command, but automatically data wasn't added.

**vendor\module_name\Cron\Test.php**

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Test {
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

   /**
    * Write to system.log
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute() {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('my_employee');
        $sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " (name, position,status) Values ('Cron','CronTesting','0')";
        $connection->query($sql);
    }
}
```

**vendor\module_name\etc\frontend\crontab.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="Vendor\Module_name\Cron\Test" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**vendor\module_name\etc\frontend\cron_groups.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="custom_crongroup">
        <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>4</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>2</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change `cron_tab` and `cron_groups` file path :-**

> **vendor\module_name\etc\crontab.xml**
>
> **vendor\module_name\etc\cron_groups.xml**

Comment: Where I add this Files Can you Provide me a Path ?

Comment: just move this file into **etc** folder

Comment: Still It is Not Working !

Comment: clean cache and try

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Ng-LAnvZ8u_VSMOutE1bvQyHESrcCsn/view?usp=sharing

It is Displayed in the Backend

Comment: yes that mean your code is working

Comment: Yes,Code is Working Properly When Run CMD command But It is Not Run Automatically.When i Run The Command The Cron Is Work And add Data into the Database But After this Is not work Automatically.

Comment: your cron run At every minute

Comment: <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
I'm Wrtting this in the Crontab.xml is it proper Way to write the Schedule ?

Comment: yes <schedule>* * * * *</schedule> means cron run At every minute

Comment: your you can set cron using this link https://crontab.guru/

Comment: <schedule>1 * * * *</schedule>
I'm Write this from your ref. Link But Still it is add on running thecommand but after 1 minute it is not add the data

Comment: Still it is Not Working :(